# Python3 with FileMaker data using pyodbc not giving actual unicode value [French and Hungary character]

Tags: python-3.7, pyodbc, filemaker

I am using Python3 to connect with FileMaker Database. The result I need to get from Database is "Pontificia Universidad Católica del Perú". But using pyodbc with unicode encoding UTF-8 is some thing like this "[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXrqx.png)". Once I tried to pass this value to html the unicode value is printing as space. I tried to encode my dbconnection object with 'UTF-8', 'LATIN1', 'iso-8859-1'. Still the result is same. Without this I am stuck for few days to continue my work. Please help to get actual value from FileMAker DB.

Comment: This is being discussed on GitHub [here](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/633).

Comment: Issue resolved on GitHub.